# meteorJS deploying to myname.meteor.com

Tags: meteor, deployment

1. I deployed my meteorJS app into myname.meteor.com. However, **when I make changes to my code, it doesn't show up on myname.meteor.com** even though the changes show up on my localhost:3000. How do I fix this problem?
2. To deploy my app, I typed meteor deploy myname.meteor.com in my terminal, but it didn't ask for a password or a username. **How do I add a password and username to claim myname.meteor.com**? (when I type "claim myname" in terminal, it says "this already belongs to you")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're editing code locally, so only localhost:3000 auto-refreshes. Your deployed code to myname.meteor.com won't change until you run `meteor deploy myname` again.
2. Type `meteor whoami` to see the current user you're logged in as. That's the user that will own whatever you deploy.

Comment: Thanks!! You're spot-on about #1. For #2, just to clarify: **how do I know what the password is? Or if I don't have one, how do I set up my password?** meteor whoami gives me my name (I'm assuming this is my meteor username?? I also use this username for my computer so I'm unsure), but what should I do if I forgot my password or email I signed up for the username with (assuming I did sign up for a password a long time ago)?

Comment: Basically the username you see is the same as your account on [Meteor.com](http://meteor.com). So for all password management stuff, go there and click on "My Account" in the upper right.